# Отображение картинок из группы вк на своем сайте

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Привет. Пишу сайт без CMS. На сайте хотел бы показывать фото с группы в Вконакте, но не могу этого сделать, пока пользователь не даст права (но они мне не нужны, так как владец группы я!).

Есть ли вариант вытянуть фото с группы автоматом, без запроса пользователя на права доступа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для метода [`photos.get()`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.get) токен/доступ/парава не обязательны, если альбом открытый. Например, запрос кого угодно по ссылке:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=-37276776&album_id=154823866&offset=100&count=2
```

вернёт JSON с данным на запрошенные 2 фотографии открытого сообщества. Т.е. вы можете на странице просто выполнять ajax запрос и по получении ответа показывать картинки.

Comment: VK.init({
    apiId: APPID
  });
VK.api("photos.getAlbums", { gid: 59215951, need_covers: 1, count:15}, function(result){
      if (result.response){  
           $.each(result.response, function(index, value) {
             //мой код
        }); 
          }else{      
            $('#ph_hold').html('Не удалось получить список альбомов ');
        } 
    });

Вот что у меня
Мне просто нужен список альбомов, и обложка и при нажатии он грузит фото который в  этом альбоме!

Comment: [Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/2q9cyuwq/). Разбирайтесь.